# Connection error Mongo DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am getting the following error message when I try to connect MongoDB in mac

> MongoDB shell version v3.4.9 connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
>   2017-11-27T12:27:26.105+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to
>   127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused 2017-11-27T12:27:26.141+0530 E QUERY    [thread1]
>   Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt
>   failed : connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13 @(connect):1:6
>   exception: connect failed

Comment: I resolved the error.
"Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db, terminating"
This was in read only form. I changed that giving 
> sudo chown -R $USER /data/db

Comment: You can post the answer . about how you have resolved your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo service mongod start
mongo
```

Comment: I got the following error message sudo: service: command not found